# Parsing GXL in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I need to parse a GXL file (a kind of XML for graph representation) into python. I have the simplest example:

```
<node id="V0001">
  <attr name="name">
    <string>V0001</string>
  </attr>
</node>

<node id="V0002">
  <attr name="name">
    <string>B</string>
  </attr>
</node>


<edge from="V0001" to="V0002">
  <attr name="name">
    <string>E0001</string>
  </attr>
</edge>
```

That gives a simple graph with nodes V0001 and V0002 connected with an edge called E0001.

What I need the program to do is to call 2 functions, that i have already. First is:

```
dw(a)
```

which adds a node using networkx library (and does a few more things for later use, that's why I have defined it myself). I want it to be called for each node with its name instead of **a**

Another one is:

```
dk(a,b)
```

which adds an edge between **a** and **b**

I know I can use a built-in python XML handling library, which I do import:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
```

Is there an elegant, clear way to do so? So I get a nice, readable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone looked for it later, here is how my dk (for reading multiple tags) works with the same **xml.etree.ElementTree** library:

```
for edge in tree.findall(".//edge"):
    start = edge.get('from')
    end = edge.get('to')
    dk(start,end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) would makes things a bit easier. Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("filename")

for node in tree.findall(".//node/attr/string"):
    node_value = node.text
    dw(node_value)
```

Comment: Thank you your fast reply. Unfortunately something didn't work. Here is my dw(a) function:

    def dw(a): 
 G.add_node(a)
 nodes.append(a)

I need those nodes in a **nodes** list as well for later. But when i print the nodes, I get:
    [<Element 'string' at 0x34f99e8>, <Element 'string' at 0x34f9ac8>]

Comment: @kjubus oops, sorry, you need to pass `node_value` to the `dw` function, fixed.

Comment: But I could use help with this **dk(a,b)** as well