# python : keep a word and drop other words between 2 tags

Tags: python, string

I'm new to Python.
I want my code to open a file in gxl format (like xml format), and read lines and find < string> tag.  After that, keep the first word and delete the other words until it meets < /string> tag.  How can i do this?  Here is an example:

This:

```
< string>dummyMainClass void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])< /string>
```

becomes this:

```
< string>dummyMainClass< /string>
```

p.s: in my file, all the first words in between string tags are not the same.

here is an example of one of my files:

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61c1afd751214a0473fd62ee74a3b1d6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example will allow you to read from the GXL file like a XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("original_file.gxl")

for node in tree.findall("/graph/node/attr/string"):
    # Retrieves the value of <string>, split on spaces and keep first element
    node.text = node.text.split(" ")[0]

# Write the modified contents to a new file
tree.write("modified_file.gxl")
```

This is based from the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954608/parsing-gxl-in-python), and considering the following GXL file structure from the provided sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<gxl>
    <graph id="ExtendedCallGraph" edgeids="true" edgemode="directed">
        <node id="N_0">
            <attr name="name">
                <string>dummyMainClass void dummyMainMethod(java.lang.String[])</string>
            </attr>
        </node>
        <edge from="N_0" to="N_1" isdirected="true" id="N_0--N_1">
        </edge>
        <edge from="N_0" to="N_2" isdirected="true" id="N_0--N_2">
        </edge>
        <node id="N_442">
            <attr name="name">
                <string>java.util.AbstractList void init()</string>
            </attr>
        </node>
        <edge from="N_442" to="N_89" isdirected="true" id="N_442--N_89">
        </edge>
        <edge from="N_442" to="N_443" isdirected="true" id="N_442--N_443">
        </edge>
        <node id="N_443">
            <attr name="name">
                <string>java.util.AbstractCollection void init()</string>
            </attr>
        </node>
        <edge from="N_443" to="N_88" isdirected="true" id="N_443--N_88">
        </edge>
        <edge from="N_443" to="N_89" isdirected="true" id="N_443--N_89">
        </edge>
    </graph>
</gxl>
```

Edit: Modified code to write-back to the file as specified in comments

Edit2: Added a sample portion of your example and modified the path

Comment: thanks. does this code keep the first word after string tag and drop the others?
i want the code to give me the new editted file.

Comment: The code has been edited to write to the same file now, thanks for the clarification! It would be easier with a sample file, even few lines.

Comment: i edited. and add a sample.please take a look again and help me if necessary .

Comment: i did tried your code but it didnt work. it didnt keep just the first word and drop the others.
what should i do?

Comment: I also get a lot of "ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)" when trying to access the file sample. Are the tags in the file really containing a space? i.e. `< gxl>` instead of `<gxl>`

Comment: no they dont have any space. you can give me your email and i send you the sample file. thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it isn't possible to [send private message in Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user).. Your profile indicates you are studying security, therefore you can understand my reticence to expose my email. The recommended method is to [link to a GitHub file or gist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/offer-a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin), would that work?

Comment: please look at this link 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61c1afd751214a0473fd62ee74a3b1d6
 its a gxl sample file

Comment: Modified the path to `/graph/node/attr/string` after testing it working on my side, please try again.